# Single quotes behavior in a Perl one-liner on Linux

Tags: linux, perl, command-line, sh, quote

Why does the second one-liner work despite the single quotes in it?

```
perl -wE 'say('Hello')'

# Name "main::Hello" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
# say() on unopened filehandle Hello at -e line 1.

perl -wE 'say length('Hello')'

# 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a shell command, `'abc'def`, `abc'def'`, `abcdef` and `'abcdef'` are all equivalent, so `'...'Hello'...'` is the same as `'...Hello...'`.

---

For `perl -wE 'say('Hello')'`, your shell calls

```
exec("perl", "-wE", "say(Hello)")
```

If the first argument of `say` is a bareword and no sub has been declared with that name, the bareword is used as a file handle.

---

For `perl -wE 'say length('Hello')'`, your shell calls

```
exec("perl", "-wE", "say length(Hello)")
```

If a bareword is found, no sub has been declared by that name, a file handle is not expected, the next token isn't `=>`, and `use strict 'subs';` is not in effect, the bareword is a string literal that returns itself.

---

Solutions:

```
perl -wE 'say("Hello")'           # exec("perl", "-wE", "say(\"Hello\")")

perl -wE 'say(q{Hello})'          # exec("perl", "-wE", "say(q{Hello})")

perl -wE 'say('\''Hello'\'')'     # exec("perl", "-wE", "say('Hello')")
```

Note that `perl` doesn't require the code to be a separate argument.

```
perl -wE'say("Hello")'            # exec("perl", "-wEsay(\"Hello\")")

perl -wE'say(q{Hello})'           # exec("perl", "-wEsay(q{Hello})")

perl -wE'say('\''Hello'\'')'      # exec("perl", "-wEsay('Hello')")
```